# Can't install Rmagick and Imagemagick on Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, imagemagick, rmagick

when I run `gem install rmagick-2.13.1.gem` from the directory in which rmagick-2.13.1.gem is I get an Error saying that it failed to build gem native extension, below which it says

```
c:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5 ... yes
Unable to get Imagemagick version
***extconf.rb failed***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack
of necessary libraries and/or headers. Check the mkmf.log file 
for more details.
```

From what I know reading the answers to FAQs on http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/install-faq.html#os, rmagick should come bundled with ImageMagick Windows Installer. The answers also mention rmagick-win32.gem. I haven't seen it anywhere. That's why I'll assume that rmagick-2.13.1.gem is what I need since it's the only one availaible, considering that FAQs refer to the older version of rmagick. So, I'm really confused about what the damned problem is.

I also took a look at mkmf.log file and the only thing that I've found there is

```
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5 ... yes
```

This whole thing confuses the hell out of me. So, any help would be hugely appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I have that on my Win7 machine.  as I remember, it can work with Ruby 1.8.6 but not 1.9 and maybe not 1.8.7

Comment: Are you sure you downloaded the Windows gem and not the Linux gem?

Comment: Yep, I've got the Windows gem.

Answer (score 4):

Download zip file from:
https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/downloads

Unzip it in a local directory

CD to that directory and type

```
gem install rmagick --local
```

Done.

If you get errors you might want to read the Readme.html file in the Zipfile

Comment: That works for version 2.12.0 but what if you need version 2.13.1?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly same problem.The "Read Me" in the downloaded Zip file now contains only this:

> Hi, everyone -
>
> We are no longer able to maintain
>   RMagick and are looking for someone or
>   some people to take over maintenance
>   of it. If you're interested or want
>   more details, please let us know at
>   admin@obtdev.com!
>
> It is a cool project, written in C and
>   Ruby, with lots of great developers
>   relying on it. The code, originally
>   written by Tim Hunter, is clean and
>   easy-to-understand, and there are a
>   lot of directions you could take it to
>   make it even more useful.
>
> We've had to stop maintaining it due
>   to ever-increasing constraints on our
>   time.
>
> Thanks,
>   - Benjamin and Omer.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
gem install win32-service --platform=mswin32
gem install rmagick --platform=mswin32
```

Comment: The first line worked, but the 2nd line still gave the same error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all clear your path environment variables. (This is the main step that people often skip, but very important). This is the main reason for the error you're facing.

Then install the rails installer (2.0.0) from here : http://railsinstaller.org/en

It'll set up ruby, rails, and everything else you need. This will also set up your environment path variables for you as well.

Next install imagemagick 6.7.9.9 or lower and while installing check the option to include C headers. Make sure you install it within the rails installer folder.

Then type this in your command prompt  `path=c:\RailsInstaller\ImageMagick-6.7.9-Q8;%path%` or whatever version you have.

Then type

```
gem install rmagick -- '--with-opt-dir="c:\RailsInstaller\ImageMagick-6.7.9-Q8"'
```

Finally edit C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.0.0\setup_environment.bat to include the path to ImageMagic

At line 25: `SET PATH=c:\RailsInstaller\ImageMagick-6.7.9-Q8;` or whatever version you have

Answer (score -1):

use [rmagick2](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/rmagick2.html) for 
    Ruby 1.8.2 and later, including Ruby 1.9
    ImageMagick 6.3.0-7 or later
RMagick 2 is the future of RMagick. This is the version that will get new methods and support new ImageMagick features.