# Error installing rmagick: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby, rmagick

I am trying to install RmMagic using the below command:

```
gem install rmagick -v=2.12.2
```

After running this command i get some error :

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.


        D:/ruby/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
Invalid drive specification.
Unable to get ImageMagick version
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=D:/ruby/bin/ruby


Gem files will remain installed in D:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2
.12.2 for inspection.
Results logged to D:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.12.2/ext/RMagick
/gem_make.out
```

Please help me in this regard. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem with rmagick to solve this add System Environment Variable

```
CLASSPATH .;C:\ImageMagick-6.5.6-Q8\include

lib C:\ImageMagick-6.5.6-Q8\lib
```

Then do

```
gem install rmagick  --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-lib=C:\ImageMagick-6.5.6-Q8\lib --with-opt-include=C:\ImageMagick-6.5.6-Q8\include
```

Comment: Hi Mukesh , Thanks for the response , but I tried the way you have mentioned in the above message , but I am still facing the same issue , I am working on ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.5

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940554/cant-install-rmagick-and-imagemagick-on-windows-7

Comment: @Mukesh: Thank you, this worked for me, but I didn't have to do the environment variable stuff. Here are my exact steps: 1-Install ImageMagick-6.5.6-Q8 to C:\. 2-When installing, check all boxes for includes. 3-Run `gem install rmagick -v '2.12.1' -- --with-opt-lib=C:\ImageMagick-6.5.6-Q8\lib --with-opt-include=C:\ImageMagick-6.5.6-Q8\include`. This finally worked for me and it installed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

What a pain this was... I definitely needed to do both the System Environment Variables AND the *specific* syntax of the command as suggested by Mukesh

To clarify the two steps:(for other novices like me)

Click properties from context menu of "Computer, click "Advanced System Settings",
click "Environment Variables", click "New" under System Variables,

use CLASSPATH for the variable name and for the value use:

`.;C:\ImageMagick-6.9.0-Q16\include;lib C:\ImageMagick-6.9.0-Q16\lib`

Then Run As Administrator the Command Prompt with Ruby terminal and execute:

`gem install rmagick -v '2.13.4' -- --with-opt-lib=C:\ImageMagick-6.9.0-Q16\lib --with-opt-include=C:\ImageMagick-6.9.0-Q16\include`

(***Make sure to update the versions number in both the Variable and gem command if necessary)